# Общий источник данных для TabItem MVVM C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как правильно сделать.

Немного контекста.

Имеется список клиентов.
Имеется TabControl.
При нажатии на SelectedItem списка клиентов - открывается TabItem.
Внутри каждого TabItem есть своя страница.
Данная страница основная, благодаря ей происходит переключение между контентом.
Эта страница может показать внутри себя другую страницу (их 4) в зависимости от условия.

Как правильно сделать общую ViewModel для 4-х страниц?
Если на каждую страницу(на все 4) в DataContext указать new ViewModel(), то в таком случае общий источник данных теряется

Если сделать Singleton, то этот источник данных станет общим для всех вкладок и по итогу в каждой вкладке будут одни и те же данные.

Как правильно поступить в данной ситуации? Надеюсь, правильно все описал. Спасибо.

Comment: А в чем отличие от предыдущего вашего вопроса? У вас уже 3-й вопрос по этой проблеме, добили бы до конца первый, решили бы проблему, нет? У вас должно быть наверно, что-то вроде `new ViewModel(someService)`, где `someSerivce` - общая логика, с общими данными, как-бы все.